# Need Help With Setting Up Multisig Wallet Contract

Tags: contract-development

I need help with setting up ETH multisig wallet contract. I used Mist and I think it's very newbie-friendly. However, there are 3 issues that I encountered:

1. I cannot set up more than 7 owners of the same multisig wallet contract. How/where to edit this?
2. I can edit the smart contract and under 'Select function' I can 'Remove Owner'. This is not something that I want. I want not to be able to touch the smart contract again after I deploy it. How to do that?
3. How do I access the same multisig wallet contract from other platform? For example, I can easily access my private key from myetherwallet and access the same personal wallet from metamask. If I want to 'export' this same multisig wallet contract to be used in another platform (outside Mist), how to do that?

**If there's no satisfying answer to the 3 points above, can you guys recommend me another newbie-friendly platform to set up multisig wallet contract? Thank you

Comment: #1 - the c_maxOwners variable controls how many owners the contract can store. #2 - you can just comment out the "addOwner / changeOwner / removeOwner" methods to disable owner alteration. #3 - not sure. I suggest you also take a look at [Gnosis Multisig Wallet](https://wallet.gnosis.pm), as it provides a web interface, and supports everything the Mist one does. As well as hire someone to do it for you, or write extensive tests on this and deploy it to a testnet before even attempting to use it on the main network as too many things can go wrong if not done properly.